# Running minikube on ubuntu in virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, kubernetes

I have installed Ubuntu on VirtualBox in Windows 10. I have also installed a Virtualbox and minikube on Ubuntu. But when I try to start minikube it returns an error saying that Virtualbox cannot be created.

> ❌  Error:         [VBOX_VERR_VMX_NO_VMX] start: Unable to start the VM: /usr/bin/VBoxManage startvm minikube --type headless failed:
>   VBoxManage: error: VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)
>   VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole

Comment: I think your processor may possibly not support virtualization. Try `grep -e svm -e vmx /proc/cpuinfo` if there's no output your cpu can't do virtualization.

Comment: @Arronical I have checked my processor supports virtualization it is just that I believe it cannot detect it in Virtualbox.

Comment: Is it enabled in the BIOS? There's often a setting there to disable/enable it.

Comment: @Arronical if you mean my system BIOS yes as for Virtualbox I don't know how to enable it. VirtualBox doesn't have the option to enable BIOS.

Comment: No your system BIOS was what I meant. I've got no other ideas I'm afraid. Are you starting it with `minikube start --no-vtx-check`?

Comment: @Arronical Yes I did and it doesn't work I really want to start minikube

Comment: Oh sorry, I've not read your question properly. Minikube does not support nested virtualization yet, running the minikube VM inside another (Ubuntu) VM. As shown in this issue https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/4530

Comment: You'd need to run minikube on a physical installation of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue that you're facing is that Minikube cannot run on a nested virtual machine. As you've installed the Minikube VM on an Ubuntu VM, running inside VirtualBox on Windows, your VM is nested.

This is a feature that may be developed in future, but until then you'll need a physical installation of Ubuntu to use Minikube.

More details can be found [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/4530) and [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/3900).